# How to obtain a Data.Data.Constr etc. from a Type Representation?

Tags: haskell, generics, reflection

I'm currently writing a minimalistic Haskell persistence framework that uses Data.Data Generics to provide persistence operations for data types in record syntax (I call them Entities here).
This works quite well overall (see code repo here: https://github.com/thma/generic-persistence), I've got just one ugly spot left.

Currently my function for looking up an entity by primary key has the following signature:

```hs
retrieveEntityById 
  :: forall a conn id. (Data a, IConnection conn, Show id) 
  => conn -> TypeInfo -> id -> IO a
```

This function takes an HDBC database connection, A `TypeInfo` object and the primary key value `id`.

The `TypeInfo` contains data describing the type `a`. This Info will be used to generate and perform a select statement for primary key lookup and contruct an instance of type `a` from the HDBC result row.

`TypeInfo` contains `Data.Data.Constr` and a description of all constructor fields that are obtained with the following function:

```hs
-- | A function that returns a list of FieldInfos representing the 
--   name, constructor and type of each field in a data type.
fieldInfo :: (Data a) => a -> [FieldInfo]
fieldInfo x = zipWith3 FieldInfo names constrs types
  where
    constructor = toConstr x
    candidates = constrFields constructor
    constrs = gmapQ toConstr x
    types = gmapQ typeOf x
    names =
      if length candidates == length constrs
        then map Just candidates
        else replicate (length constrs) Nothing
```

Deriving this kind of information works great when having an actual `Data a` value at hand (for example in my function for updating an existing entity).

But in the `retrieveEntityById` case this is not possible, as the object has yet to loaded from the DB. That's why I have to call the function with an extra `TypeInfo` parameter that I create from a sample entity.

I would like to get rid of this extra parameter, to have a function signature like:

```hs
retrieveEntityById 
  :: forall a conn id. (Data a, IConnection conn, Show id) 
  => conn -> id -> IO a
```

I tried several things like using a `Proxy` or a `TypeRep`, but I did not manage to derive my `TypeInfo` data from them.

Any hints and ideas are most welcome!

Comment: This can't really work in general, because a `Data` instance can have multiple different constructors (or none). You would need a stronger class for types with exactly one constructor. — I personally would try to build this on top of `Generic` instead of `Data`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm aware of that "one constructor" issue. For the moment I don't really care about it as I'm just playing around.
Do you think there is better support in `Generic` to support my requirements of obtaining type meta data from a `TypeRep` or `Proxy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access metadata from `Data a` constraints without a value `x :: a`:

- `dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)` is a representation of the type `a`. It takes an `undefined` argument because `Data` is an old interface from a time when `undefined` was considered more acceptable.
- `dataTypeConstrs` extracts the list of constructors from that representation.
- As you already noted in your code, although there is `constrFields` to get field names, there isn't an obvious way to get the arity of a non-record constructor. A solution to count the fields of a constructor is to use `gunfold` with the [`Const Int` functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Const.html).

Although your current approach seems specialized to types with a single constructor, this is not a fundamental limitation. For more than one constructor, you could store the constructor name in its persistent encoding, and on decoding, it can be looked up in the list from `dataTypeConstrs`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I'll try this out and will let you know if I still have issues.

Comment: The `dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)` trick did the job. Works like charm! Thanks for your help!